# (node:13584) Unhandled Promise rejection and (node:13584) possible EventEmitter memory leak detected in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, npm, promise

Unable to know how this error comes

Error:-

(node:13584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): ReferenceError: response is not defined
(node:13584) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

I have found similar issue like that

1. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9242
2. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1776
3. [NodeJS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716569/nodejs-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning)

But none to seem to answer my question

node version I am using v6.10.2 (find via node --version)

npm version I am using 3.10.10 (find via npm --version)

Now feeling fear of closing the server . How can I avoid this ? Is there any method of stopping that

Comment: Where is your code ? Show us some code to look before asking for solutions.

Comment: How can I know what some code you want ?

Comment: The code which is giving you these errors.

Comment: Mate, I already wrote I don't know how it come. Also I have multiple files in my project so unable to find error

Comment: Without code its hard to say, but a probable reason would be you have started listening to events, but you forgot to close while opening it. Even I got that when I forgot to close my Db connection. There were dangling connection, so node was crying that it exceeded the limit of listeners, which is by default 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328580/how-do-i-find-out-where-an-unhandled-promise-rejection-occured/44328885#44328885